# Creating NSNumber from another NSNumber behavior?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsarray, nsnumber

I'm trying to insert an NSNumber as a float value, into an NSArray, containing the floatValue from another NSNumber.  I'm able to create the array fine, but when I access the object, it appears to only be an integer?  I would expect that [NSNumber numberWithFloat:n] would generate a normal NSNumber with a float value..

```
int myInteger = 3;
NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInteger];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[myNum floatValue]], nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Output:

```
2012-01-09 16:39:32.664 ObjectiveCSandbox[2961:707] 3
```

Additionally, I am able to use the %i pointer fine, and when I try and use the %f pointer in NSLog, the app crashes completely.  What is going on here?  This question is more academic than anything.

Comment: Just a note: if you're creating a one-object array, you can/should use `arrayWithObject:` instead of `arrayWithObject`**s**`:`.

Comment: Note that if yu have an NSNumber with the correct value in it (as an integer), there is no point in creating a second instance with the floating point representation and, for very large values, doing so might lose precision (if I remember my floating point representation info correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default print behavior for `NSNumber` will trim off any leading zeros. So even if the underlying value is a float, if there's no actual non-zero floating-point numbers, it'll print like its an integer.

As for your second question, using both `%i` and `%f` is incorrect in your log statement, since you're logging an object. You could use `%p` to log the pointer value of the object, if you wanted, but I don't think that's useful to you at the moment. If you want to use `%f` to get printf's default float-printing behavior then you need to actually pass it a float instead of an object, as in `NSLog(@"%f", [[arr objectAtIndex:0] floatValue])`.

If all you're really interested in is whether the `NSNumber` is storing a float internally, then you can print out the results of the `-objcType` method, which will give you the `@encode`-string for the underlying value, but I'm not sure why you care what particular underlying format `NSNumber` uses to store your value, as long as it can return you the value in your desired format (e.g. by calling `-floatValue`).

Comment: Thanks Kevin, using the %f and floatValue was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the last line:

```
NSLog(@"%f", [[arr objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]);
```